# Is there a way to do a unit test in react-plotly.js?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, plotly.js

I'm creating a chart component using `react-plotly.js`,
and I want to test whether the line is drawn correctly or how long it takes to render, depending on the data that I pass to the component.

I'm writing a test code using Jest and React Testing Library.

But when I run the test code, I can't see any contents of the Plotly component. Why is it like this?

- My chart component:

  ```
  import Plotly from 'react-plotly.js';

  const Chart = ({chartData, layout}) => {
    // ...
    return (
        <div data-testid='plotly'>
          <Plotly
            data={chartData}
            layout={layout}
          />
        </div>
    );
  };
  ```
- Test code:

  ```
  import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
  describe('<PuiChart /> test', () => {
    it('matches snapshot', () => {
      const chart = render(
        <Chart
          data={[
            {
              x: [1, 2, 3],
              y: [4, 5, 6],
              name: '',
              mode: 'lines+markers' as const,
              type: 'scatter' as const,
              marker: { color: '#cacaca', line: { color: 'black', width: 1 } },
            },
          ]}
          layout={{
            title: { text: 'TITLE EXAMPLE' },
          }}
        />
      );

      screen.debug();
      expect(chart.container).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  });
  ```
- Result:

  ```html
  <div
     data-testid="plotly"
  />
  ```

Comment: You didn't use `react-plotly` library correctly. `react-plotly` exports `createPlotlyComponent` function. see https://github.com/benjeffery/react-plotlyjs#react-plotlyjs-

Comment: @LinDu Thank you so much!
As you said, I modified the code as below, and it works well.

`import Plotly from 'plotly.js-dist-min';
import createPlotlyComponent from 'react-plotly.js/factory';
const Plot = createPlotlyComponent(Plotly);`
By the way, The following link shows an example of importing and using it right away,
And my components also worked.
https://plotly.com/javascript/react/

Is there a reason why i have to use `createPlotlyComponent`?

Comment: If you're looking to benchmark rendering times, the jest dom is not a realistic environment to do that.

Comment: @possum Thank you for your reply. 
So should I use devtools to benchmark rendering time?
Or If I test using cypress (or another E2E test tool), is it possible to benchmark like I'm rendering it in real dom?